# For adults, does hearing a certain word more often induce you to instinctively or automatically use it?

Tags: language, language-processing, subconscious

**For adults twenty years and older, does hearing a word often increase the chance that you will use it instinctively?**

I thought that hearing a word more often would make you unconsciously use it more. For example, assume you know the meaning of the acronym LOL and hear it often while talking with friends. How much more likely are you to instinctively say LOL relative to how many times you heard it? If you know a word but hear it less often, how much less would you use, think, or mentally say it? For all cases, assume the subject knows what the word means and how to say it.

I am talking about the automatic or unconscious use of words, not a conscious effort to fit in or act like others. **What studies or experiments quantify the influence of hearing a word on how often you use it?** For this question, I consider mentally saying a word the same as saying it out loud. I am also curious about how much the use of a word is conscious and how much is subconscious. I found a related article about Freudian slips, but the studies linked here are hidden behind a paywall.

[*What's Really Happening When You Have a Freudian Slip.* Cherry](https://www.verywellmind.com/what-is-a-freudian-slip-2795851)